# Email Domain filter not allowing some emails to be sent

Tags: email, email-relay, office-365

We have activated Email relay to send emails from office365. We have also activated the domain filters [image] . There are a few other emails which are sent out form apex classes which stopped sending out.

If i deactivate the domain filter, then they start to work. Any idea why they wouldn't be sending out the emails when the filter is activated?
Having * for the sender and recipient i thought would allow all emails to go through.

**Update**
Taking a look at the email logs have this

> 550 5.7.64 Relay Access Denied ATTR36. For more details please refer
> to https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3169958

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_email_domain_filter.htm&type=5

Comment: @identigral i have seen this article. What i dont understand on there is that i have * on the sender and recipient and it doesnt send some emails from apex classes. Once i have the filter deactivated it does

Comment: It might be unrelated to the filter. Take a look at the [mail logs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_monitor_emails_sent_from_salesforce.htm&type=5)

Comment: @identigral Email logs have this entry550 5.7.64 Relay Access Denied ATTR36. For more details please refer to https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3169958. Thanks for the input will need to get help from the office365 admin to build the connectors i guess